# Replace numbers by symbols SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string, replace, string-formatting

I'm currently struggling..
I'm trying to convert values (Salarys) to * (stars)
That means for 3000 it should give me *** as Result.
Per 1000 should one * be made.
Can anyone help me out?

Edit:
My current solution (not working)

```
SELECT SUBSTR(LAST_NAME, 0,8) as h, round(SALARY, -3) FROM EMPLOYEES
```

So I already rounded on 1000, but how do I change it to Stars??

Comment: If you're struggling, you must have tried something.   What did you try and what error did you get?

Comment: I edited my question, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

`SELECT REPEAT('*', FLOOR(Salary / 1000));`

Simply divide your salary with 1000, then round so you have no decimals and then you repeat * x-times.

EDIT (depending on the comment):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(LAST_NAME, 0, 8) AS h, REPEAT('*', FLOOR(Salary / 1000))
FROM EMPLOYEES 
WHERE SALARY <> 0;
```

Comment: Seems logical, but how do I implement it?
`SELECT SUBSTR(LAST_NAME, 0,8) as h, round(SALARY, -3) FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE SALARY <> 0 
REGEXP_REPLACE (SALARY, '*')`